# UITabbarItem name in Caps?

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

Just wanted to ask, it is allowed to have the UITabbarItem name in Caps. 
Its not something I have come across before. So is it allowed by Apple?

Thanks

Comment: I want to put the item names in Caps? So it is allowed?

Comment: It doesn't look very nice... I think that's why you don't see many apps that do it.

Comment: I am using a custom UITabBar with a different font. So it looks totally different from the existing one. Maybe I should have mentioned that. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is allowed. I don't see any reason to disallow caps letter in tabbarItem. So you can use that without worry.